# What "whisker" means in box-and-whisker plot?

Tags: statistics, terminology

This is a bit off-topic but I can't help thinking about the reason behind naming box-and-whisker plot.

"Whisker" according to dictionary is "any of the long stiff hairs that grow near the mouth of a cat, mouse, etc." To me it seems very irrelevant. Why the word "whisker" chose for this particular type of plot. Does "whisker" have another mathematical meaning?

Comment: If you turn the box and whisker diagram on its side and draw a little face on it it looks a bit like a rectangular cat.

Comment: @ Tim: cool comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: cat whiskers]

Perhaps it's more evocative if we draw it slightly differently. Think of the single line and horizontal lines as an abstract version of this (Kazimir Malevich would be so proud).

In any case, the further you go in mathematics the lazier mathematicians get in naming things. Shout outs to "admissible", "pseudo / quasi / weak", and the horrors of "normal" and "regular".

Comment: This is the first time that I see vertical box-and-whisker plots. In my text books they are always horizontal. But now that you put it in this way I can't agree with you more.

Comment: i just modified the image on the wikipedia page. i wanted to do it with real pictures of cats but that would have been way too much effort

Comment: Adding this data to Wikipedia page is great. Though the Wikipedia page is not updated yet. Maybe somebody revert the changes!

Comment: ahahaha, no, i mean i just edited the wikipedia picture and uploaded my version to this thread. i'm not so brazen as to change the wiki version!

Answer (score 1):

"Whiskers" or "antennas" in boxplots are just continuous representations (i.e. intervals) containing those data in the data set whose distance from the 1st, resp. 3rd quantile of the data set is smaller or equal to 1.5 times the interquantile range.

This is just one possible definition: you could also use boxplots with whiskers whose endpoints are the 3rd quantile and the maximum of your data set, resp. the 1st quantile and the minimum of your dataset.

In the end, the whiskers are useful to visualize the "spread" of your data set around the interquantile range and to detect outliers.

Btw, I like the word whiskers a lot; a cat with long sensitive whiskers gets much information from the surrounding environment; a data set with long whiskers indicates the presence of a non trivial contribution coming from outliers which can be very interesting data.

Comment: Interesting! I did not know cat get information by using their whiskers. Thank for answering.